# Netbeans autocomplete XSLT/HTML

Tags: html, xslt, netbeans, autocomplete

I downloaded Netbeans 8.0.1 to create some `XSLT` files. Here is a small example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The autocomplete feature of `Netbeans` works complete without problems, if you have a simple `XSLT` file or a simple `HTML` file. But if you mix up those two files, the autocomplete feature just works for `XSLT`.
Beginning with the `<html>` tag, i don't have autocomplete anymore, even not for the `XSLT` tags at the end of the file.
Does anyone know if this is a bug or just some settings to use autocomplete for `HTML` and `XSLT`?

Comment: Did you find out how to get the autocomplete working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holy GNU, after a whole afternoon on that, I managed to get both XSL and HTML auto-complete working on the same XSL file.

**Download an XSD version of HTML5**

HTML is not XML, so we must take a look on XHTML5 (HTML serialized as XML). I've taken the XSD from [there](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.googlecode.l10n-maven-plugin/l10n-maven-plugin/1.5/xhtml5.xsd)

**Tell netbeans to use it**

The xhtml namespace http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml must use the XSD we've downloaded. So, in Tools → DTD & XML Schema → User catalog, add a local Schema where the `System ID` is `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` and the `URI` is `the xhtml5.xsd you've downloaded`.

You may need to restart netbeans (I actually restated it so many times I cannot tell whether it's required or not).

**Use the xhtml namespace in the XSL**

Now, in the XSL, tell that you're using the xhtml namespace with the attribute `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` on the root node.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    >
```

You could also have added this `xmlns` attribute to each most-top-level html node (aka, each html node that has no html node in their ancestors). You can also use `xmlns:html` on the root node, and use `<html:*>` instead of `<*>` nodes. It's useful if you have multiple namespaces like `HTML+SVG+MathML+XSL`.

**Enjoy html auto-complete**

You should then have the auto completion for html. It requires that you explicitly type the first `html` tag, but once inside an `html` tag, the auto complete works (so, if you're making a `table` inside a `xsl:template`, you'll still have to type the `<table>` but once inside, auto complete will suggest things like `<caption>`, `<thead>` and so on).

---

**What about auto-complete XSL inside the HTML?**

It requires an edit in the xhtml's XSD. We must declare the XSL namespace in the XSD using `xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"` on XSD's root node. Then, we must tell in the XSD that *every* HTML node can contain an XSL node. This is done by using `<xs:any namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" processContents="skip"/>` in all elements groups `<xs:group>`.

Once these edits are done, the XSD says *"Every HTML node can contain an element from XSL's namespace"*, so Netbeans's auto-complete will suggest XSL nodes too.

You can download the edited XSD I'm using here: http://xenos.reinom.com/stackoverflow/xhtml5.xsd

---

In case you're wondering, I made a long detailed response so you can do the same if you want to mix XSL and SVG or XSL and any other XML-XSDed format.